# Is it possible to use google server for voice recognition without Android?

Tags: voice-recognition, google-voice

Is it possible to use Google Voice Server for voice recognition in the same way as "Voice Search" application in Android does.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can also access the Google speech recognition services using the HTML speech input API. More details [here](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2011/03/talking-to-your-computer-with-html5.html)